# Losing the last column of data

Tags: mysql

After Loading data into the table and running  a query on it, it tends to lose the last column of it. Like somewhere in import process it lost it. The file i was using was UTF-8 .csv format. A
Is there anything i need to add to this :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'xxx/xxxx/Desktop/xxx/xxxx/file.csv'
INTO TABLE opendns_cc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

/Names in the path are changed due to security/

Comment: Hi, First of all, welcome to the site. There are a few problems with your question preventing answers. Please show all the code and table definitions and sample data. Please do the [tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) read through the [help section](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help)
to learn how this site works. especially how to [ask a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You will attract more answers and useful feedback.

Comment: have you tried LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'?

Comment: Thanks, seems like that  was the problem. I`ll check it with other files, but it works with this particular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add an empty field at the end of each line, and remove the last column of your table.

Otherwise check for all the line terminations (\r\n vs. \n), or the presence of \n in your contents...

It should work at the end, good luck !